# Read image in a div and send mail using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, email

I have a div Which contains images. I have to send mail. I have written following code but Not able to export images this way.

```
$('#save_btn').click(function() {
            save_chart($('#container0').highcharts());
            save_chart($('#container1').highcharts());
            save_chart($('#container2').highcharts()); 
            var dsimg = $('#imgContainer').html();
            var dataString =  'dsimg='+ dsimg ;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "email_ds.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(){
                  $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        });

<?php
if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['dsimg'];
    $email = 'xyz@gmail.com';
    $message = "success message".$name;

//send email
    mail("zyx@gmail.com", "51 Deep comment from" .$email, $message);
}
?>
```

Mail is working but in the mail no images sent.

Comment: for mail, you need to set absolute path of images..., Attachment work, But not show image in DIV.

Comment: Actually the images are dynamically generated. Its not stored yet. It's created in a div. 
save_chart($('#container2').highcharts());

Above line is creating image and appending to a div

Comment: you need to store and add an absolute path in `img src`